# Woocommerce change tag_id to name

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to know how to change category id's to the actual name of the category and vice versa. for example if i run

```
$lob = $values[data]->tag_ids;
```

$lob with then equal

```
Array
(
[0] => 184
[1] => 135
[2] => 185
)
```

How do I convert that array into an array with the names?  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) to get the full term objects which contain the name. If you do this in [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) you can convert the IDs in the array to the name:

```
$lob = $values[data]->tag_ids;

$names = array_map( function( $term_id ) {
    $term = get_term( $term_id );

    return $term->name;
}, $lob );
```